# Angular 4 routing with asp.net mvc (shared layout)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular4-router

I am building an app with asp.net mvc with angular 4. I have a shared layout which contain all the link of my page and it is .cshtml . When I give a link which will use angular routing.But when I click the link it is not working and page not showing.

**My shared Layout link Code:**

```
         <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index","Admin")">User List</a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("PermissionIndex","Admin")">Permission Index</a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("RoleCreate","Admin")">Role Create</a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("RoleIndex","Admin")">Role Index</a></li>
                        <li><a routerLink="/homes" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>  </li>
```

**This is my Home Component**:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'homes',
        templateUrl:"./home.component.html"
    })
    export class HomeComponent {

    }
```

**This is App routing module:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent },
  { path: 'homes', component: HomeComponent }

];

@NgModule({
    //imports: [
    //    BrowserModule,
    //    FormsModule,
    //    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/crisis-center/
    //],
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

When I click on home then nothing showing up.
```

Answer (score 1):

I did face the same problem while trying to add Angular to an existing ASP.Net MVC website.

I configured my routing to every path starting with "/app" to be redirected to my AppController (main page of my Application)

I had a shared Layout between the MVC and Angular pages containing the menu with a lot of @Url.Action and @Action.Links.

This was my initial MVC routing and the one that was causing the issue.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
            new
            {
                serverRoute = new ServerRouteConstraint(url => !url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/app", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "angular",
            "{*url}",
            new {controller = "App", action = "Index"}
        );
    }
}
```

The problem with this, is that an @Url.Action is being resolved:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")">Link</a>
```

on the angular page, the url.PathAndQuery will contain "/app" and will not match with the MVC route. Making impossible to resolve the @Url.Action.

For solving this I Created a custom constraint filtering by [RouteDirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedirection(v=vs.110).aspx), matching the Default route when it is UrlGeneration (this is the value when it is trying to resolve a @Url.Action).

This is how my final routing looks like:

```
public class AngularConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match
    (
        HttpContextBase httpContext,
        Route route,
        string parameterName,
        RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection
    )
    {
        return routeDirection == RouteDirection.UrlGeneration ||
               !httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWith("/app", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}

public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
            new
            {
                AngularConstraint = new AngularConstraint()
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "angular",
            "{*url}",
            new {controller = "App", action = "Index"}
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a huge help! Thank you!